# separate data in 2 groups with elements of each pair in separate groups

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset consisting of two columns `player1` and `player2` for a group of n players. each 2 players play with each other twice (once i as `player1` and j as `player2` and once i as `player2` and j as `player1`)

I want to separate my data so that I have a `games1` dataframe which includes all the games where it's the two players' first game and a dataframe `game2` which includes all their second games (obviously each sub dataframe is half the size of my original dataframe)

I've considered iterating with a for loop over all the rows and defining a flag to determine whether it's the first game two players are playing or not. I was just wondering if there was an easier/faster way.

I have a data.frame()

```
# reproducible exmaple
df1 <- read.table(text = "player1  player2
1:         1        2
2:         2        3
3:         3        2
4:         1        3
5:         2        1
6:         3        1", header = TRUE)
```

I need:

```
data.frame()
     player1  player2
1:         1        2
2:         2        3
3:         1        3
```

and

```
1:         3        2
2:         2        1
3:         3        1
```

Comment: Eventually `df1$game <- ifelse(df$player1<df$player2, 1, 2)` for defining the grouping variable.

Comment: @jogo the example looks like this by chance,my data is sorted by time. the game between `3` as `player1` and `2` as `player2` could come before `2` as `player1` and `3` as `player2` so I have to group them according to their order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly ugly solution can be to sort rowwise, and get the two groups by `duplicated(...)` and `duplicate(..., fromLast = TRUE)`, i.e.

```
d1 <- data.frame(t(apply(df1, 1, function(i) sort(i, decreasing = TRUE))))

df1[!duplicated(d1),]
#   player1 player2
#1:       1       2
#2:       2       3
#4:       1       3

#AND

df1[!duplicated(d1, fromLast = TRUE),]
#   player1 player2
#3:       3       2
#5:       2       1
#6:       3       1
```

Since it is not recommended to keep a lot of objects in your global environment, you can add them in a list, i.e.

```
list1 <- list(df1[!duplicated(d1),], df1[!duplicated(d1, fromLast = TRUE),])
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have to identify the two players. Then you can use the combination for grouping:

```
# reproducible exmaple
df1 <- read.table(text = "player1  player2
1:         1        2
2:         2        3
3:         3        2
4:         1        3
5:         2        1
6:         3        1", header = TRUE)
df1$players <- with(df1, 
        ifelse(player1 < player2, paste(player1, player2, sep='.'), paste(player2, player1, sep='.')))
df1$game <- ave(df1$players, df1$players, FUN=function(x) c(1,2))
# > df1
#    player1 player2 players game
# 1:       1       2     1.2    1
# 2:       2       3     2.3    1
# 3:       3       2     2.3    2
# 4:       1       3     1.3    1
# 5:       2       1     1.2    2
# 6:       3       1     1.3    2
```

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
# reproducible exmaple
df1 <- read.table(text = "player1  player2
1:         1        2
2:         2        3
3:         3        2
4:         1        3
5:         2        1
6:         3        1", header = TRUE)
setDT(df1)
df1[, players:=ifelse(player1 < player2, paste(player1, player2, sep='.'), paste(player2, player1, sep='.'))]
df1[, game:=c(1,2), players][]
```

Using the function `rowid()` this can be shorten to (thx to @Frank):

```
df1[, game := rowid(paste(pmin(player1, player2), pmax(player1, player2)))]
```

The splitting of the groups can be done in both variants by the function `split()` from base `R`:

```
split(df1, by="game", keep = FALSE)
```

The result will be a list of two data.table-objects.

Comment: Re data.table, could also do `df1[, match := rowid(paste(pmin(player1, player2), pmax(player1, player2)))]; split(df1, by="match", keep = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

A Slightly clean solution :

```
  df2
       player1 player2
    1:       1       2
    2:       3       2
    3:       2       3
    4:       1       3
    5:       2       1
    6:       3       1

game1<-df2[!duplicated(t(apply(df2, 1, sort))),]

 game1
  #     player1 player2
  #  1:       1       2
  #  2:       3       2
  #  4:       1       3

game2<-setdiff(df2,game1)

game2
 #     player1 player2
 #  1       2       3
 #  2       2       1
 #  3       3       1
```